# How to verify the limit of a sequence using the definition?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$\let\biconditional\leftrightarrow$
Given the definition of limit of a sequence
$$ \lim_ {n \to \infty} a_n = a \biconditional \forall\epsilon>0 ,\exists\nu>0: \forall n>\nu, |a_n - a| < \epsilon $$

i want to verify this limit using the definition:
$$\lim_ {a_n \to \infty} \frac{n-4}{3n+1} = \frac{1}{3}$$

How can I do that?

**EDIT:**
I've found the solution on the book:
$\nu = \frac{\frac{13}{\epsilon-3}}{9}$
but I get
  $\nu > \frac{39 - \epsilon}{\epsilon 3} $
What is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon$, and consider $$\left|\frac{n-4}{3n+1}-\frac13\right|=\frac{13}{9n+3}<\epsilon$$

By definition we wish to find $\nu$ which would normally depend mainly on $\epsilon$ so that for any $n>\nu$, the above inequality holds. Can you find such a $\nu$ such that $\frac{13}{9n+3}<\epsilon$ holds?

Comment: I just try to solver for n right?

Comment: @reuseman yes, if you do then what do you get?

Comment: $n > \frac{39-\epsilon}{\epsilon 3}$ ?

Comment: @reuseman we should get $\frac{13}{9\epsilon}-\frac13$

Comment: ok yes that's right, but on the book it's $\nu = \frac{\frac{13}{\epsilon-3}}{9}$, for some reason i don't get the step

Comment: @reuseman hmm, by that do you mean $\frac19\left(\frac{13}{\epsilon-3}\right)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66463/discussion-between-reuseman-and-jihoon-kang).

Answer (score 0):

HINT:we have $$\left|\frac{n-4}{3n+1}-\frac{1}{3}\right|=\left|\frac{3n-12-3n-1}{3(3n+1)}\right|=\frac{13}{3(3n+1)}$$

Comment: Why denominator is $3n+1$ and not $3(3n+1)$?

Comment: sorry i forgot to type the $3$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left|\frac{n-4}{3n+1}-\frac{1}{3}\right|=\left|\frac{-13}{3(3n+1)}\right|=\frac{13}{3(3n+1)}<\epsilon$$
Only need to have
$$n>\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{13}{3\epsilon}-1\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The tool we use in this kind of problems is the so called Archimidean property.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Now we need to find $N$ such that for each $n>N,\ |\dfrac{n-4}{3n+1}-\dfrac{1}{3}|<\epsilon$.

Let's observe that $ |\dfrac{n-4}{3n+1}-\dfrac{1}{3}|=|\dfrac{3n-12-3n-1}{9n+3}|=\dfrac{13}{9n+3}<\dfrac{13}{9n}$.

Now if we can make $\dfrac{13}{9n}<\epsilon$ then we are done. So the trick is to invoke the Archimidean property and choose $N>\dfrac{13}{9\epsilon}$. Because then $n>N\implies\ n>\dfrac{13}{9\epsilon}\implies\ \dfrac{13}{9n}<\epsilon$. So to complete the proof let's write:

Choose $N>\dfrac{13}{9\epsilon}$. Then for each $n>N,\   |\dfrac{n-4}{3n+1}-\dfrac{1}{3}|=|\dfrac{3n-12-3n-1}{9n+3}|=\dfrac{13}{9n+3}<\dfrac{13}{9n}<\epsilon$.